# Modifying \answerline in the exam class

Tags: formatting, counters, exam

When using the exam class, is there a way to change the formatting of the item answer blanks created by `\answerline`?

For a question, the label is 1.

For a part, the label is (a)

For a subpart, the label is i.

I would like them all to be (1), (a), and (i) respectively.

For example

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question First one \answerline
\begin{parts} 
\part first part \answerline
\begin{subparts}
    \subpart A subpart \answerline
    \end{subparts}
\end{parts}     
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine `\questionlabel` and `\subpartlabel` which control the decorations around the numbers corresponding to questions and subparts, respectively:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{(\thequestion)}
\renewcommand\subpartlabel{(\thesubpart)}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question First one \answerline
\begin{parts} 
\part first part \answerline
\begin{subparts}
    \subpart A subpart \answerline
    \end{subparts}
\end{parts}     
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]