# How to change text on answerline in exam class

Tags: exam, questionnaire

How to replace text on answerline

As per exam class manual; i'm able to add answerline for MCQ using tex mentioned below

```
\begin{questions}
\question
Who’s buried in Grant’s tomb?
\answerline
\question
What was the color of George Washington’s white horse?
\answerline
\question
Which is heavier: A pound of feathers, or a pound of lead?
\answerline
\end{questions}
```

which gives output as [image]

I'm looking for option to get it updated as

[image]

Can you please suggest; how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine `\answerline`:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\answerline[1][{}]{%
  % One optional argument, the default value of which is empty.
  \ifx\@queslevel\ques@ref
    \let\ans@l=\questionlabel
  \else
    \ifx\@queslevel\part@ref
      \let\ans@l=\partlabel
    \else
      \ifx\@queslevel\subpart@ref
        \let\ans@l=\subpartlabel
      \else
        \ifx\@queslevel\subsubpart@ref
          \let\ans@l=\subsubpartlabel
        \else
          % Oops; no question level defined.
          % We must be outide of the questions environment.
          % Just leave out the label, I guess:
          \def\ans@l{}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \par \nobreak \vskip \answerskip
  \hfill Answer)~%
  \ifprintanswers
    %\ans@l~
\hbox to 0pt{\hbox to \answerlinelength{\hrulefill}\hss}%
    \raise \answerclearance\hbox to \answerlinelength{%
      \CorrectChoice@Emphasis \hfil #1\hss}%
  \else
    %\ans@l~
\hbox to \answerlinelength{\hrulefill}%
  \fi
  \par
}% answerline
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question
Who’s buried in Grant’s tomb?
\answerline
\question
What was the color of George Washington’s white horse?
\answerline[mmm]
\question
Which is heavier: A pound of feathers, or a pound of lead?
\answerline
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

At the expense of loading an additional package (`xpatch`), you can quickly patch the existing `\answerline` macro.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\def\NewAnswerLabel{Answer)}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\questionlabel}% <search>
  {\NewAnswerLabel}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
Who’s buried in Grant’s tomb?
\answerline
\question
What was the color of George Washington’s white horse?
\answerline
\question
Which is heavier: A pound of feathers, or a pound of lead?
\answerline
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I learned about `\answerline` and patching it from the following questions/answers:

[Modifying \answerline in the exam class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50158/modifying-answerline-in-the-exam-class)

[\answerline to the right of a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82152/answerline-to-the-right-of-a-question)

[\answerline to the right of a question with dot line between answer line and question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94374/answerline-to-the-right-of-a-question-with-dot-line-between-answer-line-and-que)