# answerline command in exam class

Tags: macros, exam, xpatch

I am trying to modify `\answerline` to do two things:

1. have answer labels which could be different for each question;
2. have the answers (just the answers and not the labels) done in a color of one's choosing (There is `\SolutionEmphasis{}` which may be handy for doing this but I don't know how to exploit it to also achieve 1. above).

Ideally, the final macro, call it `\solutionline` should be able to respond to `\solutionline{$H=$}{3}` and produce:

> H = _____**3**______

with 3 in a different color.

Following Steven B. Segletes' answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159616/how-to-change-text-on-answerline-in-exam-class) question, I tried the following but I now understand that this does not work.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\answerprompt}[1][\textbf{Answer:}]{#1}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\questionlabel}% <search>
  {\answerprompt}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

  \newcommand{\solutionline}[2]{\answerprompt{#1}\answerline[#2]}

  \usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\hfil #1}% <search>
  {\hfil \color{blue}{#1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
 \printanswers

\begin{document}
Hello!

\begin{questions}
  \question Hello there! \answerline[Back at you!]
  \question There! \answerline[Hey!]
  \question Hey! \solutionline{H}{T} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just replace `\newcommand{\solutionline}[2]{\answerprompt{#1}\answerline[#2]}` with `\newcommand{\solutionline}[2]{\renewcommand{\answerprompt}{#1}\answerline[#2]}`. This will, however, also remove the bold style from the answer labels …

Comment: @JasperHabicht Hah, `\renewcommand` it is! Thank you! (Also I am not sure what you mean by "remove the bold style from the answer labels, but could we not factor that into it as `\newcommand{\solutionline}[2]{\renewcommand{\answerprompt}{\textbf{#‌​1}}\answerline[#2]}`? (Could you please post your comment as an answer too?)

Comment: But actually, I think, Arzigoglu’s answer is better, because: 1) the code is cleaner, 2) it patches `\ans@l` which actually stores the answer prompt, 3) it makes it possible to use different colors. So, why not use this answer?

Comment: Now that I've corrected the answer, doesn't it do what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry that I could not accept it earlier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following definition for `\solutionline`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\solutionline}[3][blue]{%
\begingroup%
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\ans@l~}% <search>
  {\answerprompt[#2]~}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\answerline[\textcolor{#1}{#3}]%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\newcommand{\answerprompt}[1][\textbf{Answer:}]{#1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\solutionline}[3][blue]{%
\begingroup%
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\ans@l~}% <search>
  {\answerprompt[#2]~}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\answerline[\textcolor{#1}{#3}]%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

 \printanswers

\begin{document}
Hello!

\begin{questions}
  \question Hello there! \answerline[Back at you!]
  \question There! \answerline[Hey!]
  \question Hey! \solutionline{H}{T}
  \question Hey! \solutionline[green]{H}{green}
  \question There! \answerline[Hey!]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, did you notice the "failure" printed after "Hey!" in 3 and 4? I have a feeling the fragment `##1` is not a part of the macro `\answerline` (for eg, try `texdef -t latex -c exam answerline` on your terminal). But I don't know how the rest of it works though. Confusing to me.

Comment: I will experiment more and post this pm...

Comment: @kan Yes, I was experimenting and I've posted the wrong solution :-( Now I've corrected it and should be OK.